# what is the update method in laravel 5.4 crud?

Tags: php, laravel, crud

i just trying to crud system. for that into controller store function my code is

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    Article::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'content' => $request->content,
        'live' => (boolean)$request->live,
        'post_on' => $request->post_on
        ]);

    return redirect('/articles');
}
```

it's enough to store data, but when i want to edit article & save again then what will be my edit function code? i have no idea. i trying same code into edit function & it create new article not update. so what will be right code for edit function? thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write free code for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 11):

Resource controller method for update is `update()`. Eloquent method for `update()` is `update()` too, so you can do this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Article::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/articles');
}
```

You also can use the same controller and Eloquent method for both crerate and update data `updateOrCreate()` method.

Comment: @Masum you're using completely different code from the code I've shown. `fill()` method doesn't update data, it's just fills out attributes. Use `$article->save();` after `fill()` or use `update()` as I've shown.

Comment: it shwos this errors                                                            
                                                                                            
     SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `_method` = PUT, `_token` = l1ZyYVMAQJCAU6mzVXFEYqt2hUSQyAkqws9804aj, `content` = sadfasdf, `post_on` = 2017-04-25T03:43, `Create_Post` = Submit, `updated_at` = 2017-04-25 15:48:20 where `id` = 13)

Comment: by fill method it dont shows any errors but it does not updated data

Comment: @Masum show guarded and fillable arrays from the Article model, please. Or just do this `->fill($request->except(['_method', '_token']))`

Comment: Thanks all . i got solution & that is                                                            
     $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->update($request->all());    thank to every one for support me

Answer (score 4):

You can also update it as object format like this.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $article = Article::find($id);
   $article->user_id = auth()->id();
   $article->content = $request->content;
   $article->live = (boolean)$request->live;
   $article->post_on = $request->post_on;
   $article->save();
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//route//
Route::any('/update/{id}', 'ProductController@update');

//controller//

 public function update(Request $request, $id) {
 $product = $request - > all();

 Product::find($id) - > update($product);
 return redirect('/product') - > with('message', 'Success', compact('product'));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: It's better if there is some explanation in your answer about what code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->fill($request->all());
}
```

sure you should add Your column attributes to $fillable array in Your model

```
 protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'content', 'live'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    Article::where('id', $id)->update($request->except(['_token']));
    return redirect('/articles');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you auto-generate resource controller for a specific Model using `php artisan make:model -a Artical` then you have the `update()` function like below:

```
public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    //
}
```

Here, Lavarel automatically fetch the `Article` object into `$article`. So, you can save the `$request` data like below:

```
public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $article->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('article.index'); // or your desired location :)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
            $info = array('user_id' =>$request->user()->id,
              'content' => $request->content, 'live'=>$request->live);

            DB::table('article')->where('id', $id)->update($info);

            session()->flash('success', 'Update Successfully');
            return redirect('/article');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are having two actions right, the create and update, so for a real crud in laravel you might have these two in a separated logic methods the `store()` and `update()`:

```
/**
 * This is a resource create method which is a HTTP POST.
 */
public function store(Request $request) {
     // create a new item in database
}

/**
 * This is a resource update which is a HTTP PUT METHOD.
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
     // update the item in database
}
```

You set up your routes with`POST` for creating and `PUT` to update then your doing a proper crud resource.

I recommend you to separate the create logic off the update logic and if you have sort of unique data then you should validate its value before creating a new resource.