# Laravel - How to Update Dynamic Input Fields

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8, I have this code:

```
public function add(Request $request){
    if( $request->ajax() ){

        $rules = array(
            'first_name.*'  => 'required',
            'country.*'  => 'required'
        );

        $error = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);

        if($error->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'error' => $error->errors()->all(),
            ]);
        }

        $first_name = $request->first_name;
        $country = $request->country;

        for( $count = 0; $count < count($first_name); $count++ ){
            $data = array(
                'first_name' => $first_name[$count],
                'country' => $country[$count],
            );
            $insert_data[] = $data;
        }

        DynamicField::insert($insert_data);
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'Data added Successfully',
        ]);

    }
}
```

This successfully Inserts record.

How do I do the update to this same code?

I mean public function update ...

Comment: you need get `id` from request to determine which record in database to update.if you want combine update and insert,then if request has `id` that is update,if `id` not exists,that is insert

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614864/5957890